# Which release of Xubuntu has PipeWire by default?

Tags: xubuntu, pipewire

According to release notes 22.10 does not have it but what about later releases?

Comment: Ubuntu 22.10 (along with all flavors) is *End-of-Life* and thus unsupported on this site (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic), and many other Ubuntu sites, unless your question is specific to moving to a supported release of Ubuntu.  https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2023/07/27/ubuntu-22-10-kinetic-kudu-end-of-life-reached-on-july-20-2023/   https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades

Comment: Why not just look, eg. https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/xubuntu/releases/23.10/release/xubuntu-23.10-desktop-amd64.manifest shows what is included on the 23.10 or *mantic* ISO, and you can search for pipewire there pretty easily...  Likewise other ISOs via the *manifest* files as quickly..  OR you can read/scan release notes yourself too if you wish.  (*in my own case I could `grep` the manifests on a local drive given they're all there anyway... there are many ways, however 22.10 is EOL & thus off-topic*)

Comment: @guiverc This question is not off-topic as the OP does not ask about an EoL release. They ask about which release above 22.10 comes with a specific feature. Just mentioning an EoL release does not automatically make questions off-topic. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That would be [23.04](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2022/12/xubuntu-23-04-adds-pipewire-flatpak-to-default-install). From the link from omgubuntu.co.uk

> Xubuntu 23.04 Adds PipeWire & Flatpak to Default Install
>
> A couple of compelling new open source technologies are present in latest development builds of Xubuntu 23.04, which is due for release in April of next year.
>
> Both PipeWire, the newer and less buggy multimedia stack, and Flatpak, the sandboxed package management, have been adopted by Ubuntu’s lightweight sibling. Other Ubuntu flavours adopted PipeWire during the 22.10 cycle, and Ubuntu MATE added native Flatpak support in its 22.04 LTS rel

Comment: Thanks for picking that up.

Comment: I found it now also in https://wiki.xubuntu.org/releases/23.04/release-notes